# Is the JavaFX default font platform independent?

Tags: fonts, javafx

I know that JavaFX is platform independent, but what about the fonts it uses?

**Questions**

- Are the fonts the same on all platforms, especially the system font, i. e. when you set no font at all?
- Do they all support the same set of unicode characters?

**Problem**

My particular problem are 4 unicode characters:

```
spade: \u2660
heart: \u2665
diamond: \u2666
club: \u2663
```

Used via e. g.

```
     Text text = new Text( "\u2660");
     text.setFont( Font.font( null, 48));
```

I created a deck of cards that consists solely of text and no images, neither svg. Of course it would be all for nothing if the system font on mac/linux isn't the same as on windows and doesn't have these 4 special characters.

*By the way, in case someone with a mac or linux system could try it, [here's a gist with the cards](https://gist.github.com/Roland09/e00f7e97852c9113877b). It should look like this:*

[image]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not. I toyed around with JavaFX to Android conversion. It turned out that the symbols were missing in the cards.